# Prove that a sequence diverges to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove that $(s_{n})= \frac{n^{2} - 2}{n+1}$ diverges to $+ \: \infty$, using the definition of divergence. $\forall M \in \mathbb{R} \: \exists$  N such that n $>$ N implies that $(s_{n}) $>$ M.$

This is what I have thus far.

$\frac{n^{2} - 2}{n+1}$ $>$ $\frac{2n^{2}}{3n}$ $=$ $\frac{2n}{3}$ $>$ $M$, for $n \geq 4$.

Let $n=\frac{3M}{2}$ and $N$=max{$4, \frac{3M}{2}$}.

$\frac{n^{2} - 2}{n+1}$ $>$ $\frac{2n^{2}}{3n}$ $=$ $\frac{2n}{3}$ $>$ $M$.

$\therefore lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \: \frac{n^{2} - 2}{n+1}=+ \: \infty$.

Is this the correct way to prove that $(s_{n})$ diverges to $+ \: \infty$, and did I go about it correctly?

Comment: i think it must be $n\geq 3$

Comment: Does it matter what $n$ is defined to be?

Comment: no it doesn't matter it was only a remark by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be enough to note that $$\frac{n^{2} - 2}{n+1}\geqslant n-2.$$

Comment: $\frac{n^{2}}{n+1}$ $\geq$ $n-2$ $>$ $M$? This would also prove divergence?

Comment: I could then let $N$=max{$0, M+2$}?

Comment: Why are you introducing $\frac{n^2}{n+2}$ to study the behaviour of $\frac{n^2-2}{n+2}$? You might want to stick to what I wrote. // Indeed, $n-2\geqslant M$ for every $n\geqslant\max\{M+2,0\}$.